# Multiple Consumer setup for Single Producer with 4 partitions Kafka Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have created a simple producer with 4 partitions and now want to create 4 consumers in a consumer group to consume data from each partition.
How can I do that?

**Consumer Code**

```
    public class KafkaConsumer {
    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public  static DataFrame reqFieldBOIDDf;
    public static DataFrame df ;
    static SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()

                     .setAppName("kafka-sandbox")

                     .setMaster("local[*]")

                     .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","localhost"); //for cassandra

             static JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    private static long lastOffset;
            public static void main(String[] str) throws InterruptedException {
               execute();
            }
            private static void execute() throws InterruptedException {

                    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = createConsumer();       consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("KafkaConsumerTopic6"));
                    processRecords(consumer);
                    System.out.println("Inside execute");
            }
            private static KafkaConsumer<String, String> createConsumer() {
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
                    String consumeGroup = "cg1";
                    props.put("group.id", consumeGroup);
                    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
                    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "101");
                    props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "1035");
                    props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", "3000");
                    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "6001");props.put("max.poll.records","500");
props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
                   props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
                    return new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
            }
            private static void processRecords(KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer) throws InterruptedException  {
                  while (true){
                           ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
                            lastOffset = 0;
                            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                            lastOffset = record.offset();
                            list.add(record.value());
                             }
                   }
            }
```

Small piece of code would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just start 4 consumers the same way you start your 4 producers.

Make sure they all have the same `group.id` setting and make them all subscribe to the topic (or topics if it's 4 topics with 1 partition). As they'll be in the same group, Kafka will automatically assign one consumer to each partition.